# C# String to Float

Tags: c#

When I convert a string to a float I get my answer plus a bunch of junk decimals. How do I fix this? Is this floats error I'm seeing?

```
string myFloat = "1.94";
float f = float.Parse(myFloat);
```

It needs to be  a float for database reasons ...

By junk I mean 1.94 turns into: 1.94000005722046

Comment: Check out the IEEE standard for floats, I doubt 1.94 is a floating point value that actually exists, the other junk you get are the values used to produce the closest representation to 1.94 possible (fraction bits are in the form of 1/2^n and there for you will never get .94).

Comment: what do you mean junk like 1.94000001 or 1.9399998

Comment: Where do you see those decimal points ?  what is the exact value that is returned in `f`

Comment: There was an interesting talk by Jon Skeet on tony the [pony](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx). I suggest you to go and read it.

Comment: also sqlservers float is really a double which will give you a more accurate representation

Comment: @rerun I've updated the question to answer yours

Comment: Convert it to a double first?

Comment: What happens if you use `float f = 1.94f`? I strongly suspect you'll get exactly the same result - it isn't to do with parsing... please tell us more about why you think you need to use `float`.

Comment: @rerun changing it to a double fix it. If you want to put that as an answer I will select it as the solution. thanks for all the help!

Comment: Changing to a double does not fix anything. You need to take a minute and absorb the fact that `1.94` cannot be represented in binary floating point format.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand your point. But all I needed was 1.94, a string to be stored in a db table as a float. Changing the conversion to a double correct the "junk" and I can still store it as a float in the table.

Comment: No, you are doing it all wrong.

Comment: As mentioned, that's just not a value that fits into a `float`; it doesn't have a binary representation within the confines of IEEE754, basically.  Even if you assign the value directly in C, you get that same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it to a double to get a more accurate representation but if you need it exactly
You cannot fix this this is how floats are represented in computers.  If you use the decimal data type you will get an exact representation.

```
string myFloat = "1.94";
decimal f = decimal.Parse(myFloat);
```

And then do the conversion to double when you store it to the database.  You could still get some noise in the database. The only way to be sure to get rid of this is to use numeric in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use float / double if you want a precise representation of your parsed number. In case you need that you must use `decimal`. For money amounts its almost always required to use `decimal`. So keep that in mind.

Please read about how floating point numbers are represented internally:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

How 1.94 is represented internally by a float can be tested in this calculator:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=1.94

As you see its `1.940000057220458984375`.

---

Databases support the `decimal` datatype:

- **Oracle** offers DECIMAL: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html
- **SQL Server** offers DECIMAL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187746.aspx
- **MySQL** offers DECIMAL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html